# result in math mode like radicals and fractions on casio fx-992

Tags: calculator

I want to solve the equation
$$
z^2 -(\sqrt{3} +\mathrm{i}\sqrt{2}) z + \mathrm{i} \sqrt{6}=0
$$
Using the casio fx-992 plus calculator. To do this, I followed the instructions given in this video: https://youtu.be/QmRZ2ahYxFE

in complex mode (Shift + Mode (Setup)), I do the requested manipulations, instead of having a result like √3 -i√2, I get 1-4.89897979486 i.

I know there's been a mistake on my part.

**Question:**  How to get a result in math mode like radicals and fractions?

Thank you for your answer and for the consideration you have given me.

Comment: I know nothing about your calculator, but the correct solutions for the quadratic equation are $\sqrt{3}$ and $i\sqrt{2}$. So if you made an error, it is not only in the part where you make sure that you get a formula instead of a decimal result, you decimal result is also wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. It's not the result that counts, but how to get the result in radicals. 
Thank you in advance for your answer.